# Why Skype application closes before connecting?

Tags: 14.04, skype

Hello. When I enter my username and password in Skype 4.3 Linux and when I connect the application shuts down. We are several in this case, and this happens with Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10 version live and installed.

Even after a reinstallation of the application the problem persists, do you have a solution to this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please use English on this site.

Comment: It might be useful to run Skype from a command line (`skypeforlinux`) so that any error messages that get generated can be viewed. You might want to include this output in your question, as that information might be useful in troubleshooting the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/end-of-life-of-skype-for-linux-43/70fe7036-ddf3-4fa3-9c06-1bca3ec0226c?auth=1) Microsoft decided to force people to upgrade to newer Skype versions and the old ones cease to work since a few weeks already. This might probably be related to [Skype moving from peer-to-peer to being cloud based](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12381/what-does-it-mean-that-skype-is-moving-from-peer-to-peer-to-the-cloud).

> As announced earlier this year, the old Skype for Linux v4.3 is at its
>   end-of-life and will be decommissioned in the upcoming weeks.
>
> You will be automatically signed out of Skype until you update.
>   Please, update to the new Skype 8.x, which is ready for you with lots
>   of improvements at Skype.com.
>
> In case you hit any issues, please check known issues, system
>   requirements, or post your questions directly to this forum. All your
>   feedback will be greatly appreciated.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> The Skype Team
>   ([source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/end-of-life-of-skype-for-linux-43/70fe7036-ddf3-4fa3-9c06-1bca3ec0226c?auth=1))

To get the newer version you should download the latest `.deb` file from Microsoft and install it with `gdebi` or `dpkg` (shouldn't make a difference but `gdebi` is a bit more secure when it comes to dependencies).

```
wget https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Be aware, the new Skype will create a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and will do so every time it updates if the file does not exist with the exact name Skype chosen for it. So renaming the file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` only calls for trouble in form of duplicated source list entries. You as well want to remove any before existing files for Skype in your `sources.list.d` directory.

([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409438) which is an answer by my self on U&L Stackexchange)